# Emojis adding to keyboard

Tags: android, emoji

So in my app the user can create their own emojis. I want the user to be able to use the emojis in any chat based app.  I wanted to know my options to do this.

Could I add the emojis to the users keyboard directly?
Would I have to create a new keyboard and add emojis and set it as the users keyboard?

Other options?

Comment: Pretty sure this cant be done. Unless both users have the app installed. Or it would require third parties to include some connection between their app and yours.

Comment: @Gary Johnson would it be possible to set the users keyboard to mine that has the emojis already set on it so they could then use the emojis. I would have the keyboard intergrated with my app.

Comment: The problem is that the `emjoi` would have to be converted to some type of value, like a hex value `#123456` and then the other users phone would have to know what that value meant and convert it to the correct character. The user might be able to see their `emjois` on their keyboard but when they send them the other users phone wouldn't be able to interpret it.

Comment: This is why you sometimes see an `emjoi` as an X with a box around it. That is because the app/phone couldn't interpret the value and resorted to the error value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Keyboards define what keys they have themselves.  There is no global add to keyboard function.  You could write your own keyboard for your app (although I really wouldn't suggest it, writing good autocorrect and swyping algorithms requires years of effort).  But even then they wouldn't be visibile in another app unless you use emojis in whatever font they use.  You'd also piss off your users-  people don't like having their keyboard switched out from under them.